# Showing the preimage of a ball is nonmeagre

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a Boreal Measurable linear operator where $X$ is a Banach space and $Y$ is a seperable normed vector space. I would like to show $A=\{x \mid \lVert f(x) \rVert <1/2\}$ is nonmeagre Boreal.

So I think Boreal is free by hypothesis since $A$ is the preimage of a ball but I can't make any progress on nonmeagre. Banach space makes me think I have to use BCT to write things like $cl(A^c)=X$ so $f(cl(A^c))=f(X)$ and get a contradiction but I'm stuck here. I also can't see where separability of $Y$ could be used.

EDIT; tentative solution but I'm still not using the separability of Y nor the completeness of X, so something is probably wrong;

Suppose A meagre. Then $cl(A^c)=X$ and $f(cl(A^c))=f(X)$. Take $y \in f(A)$ then there must be a sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq1}$ in $A^c$ with $x_n \rightarrow f^{-1}(y)$. But then $\lVert f(x_n) \rVert \geq 1/2$ for all $n$ so $[f(x_n)]_{n\geq 1} \subset B_{1/2}(0)^c$. But $f(x_n) \rightarrow y$, which is impossible since $B_{1/2}(0)^c$ is closed and $y \in B_{1/2}(0)$.

This cannot be correct as I haven't used any of the hypothesis of the question.